# Data Driven Restrictions of Plan Selections

Tags: sql, join, filter, restriction

I have a complex data structure I am working with and I am not quite sure how to tackle it in a single SQL query, although my gut tells me this should be possible to do.

The essence of what I am doing is trying to display the results of available plans for a given vendor based on the selected hardware model. The results should adhere to only possible combinations, and the plans contain restrictions which are currently stored as key/value pairs in a restrictions table. Below is a simplification of what I am working with:

(I will use a wireless device analogy since almost everyone is familair with cell phones)

models Table

---

```
model_id
vendor_id
is_data
is_voice
is_4g
is_3g
```

Sample Data:

```
model_id,vendor_id,is_data,is_voice,is_4g,is_3g
DeviceA,Sprint,1,1,0,1
DeviceB,Sprint,1,0,1,0
DeviceC,Sprint,0,1,0,0
DeviceD,Sprint,0,1,0,0
DeviceE,Sprint,0,1,0,0
DeviceF,Verizon,1,1,0,1
DeviceG,Verizon,1,0,1,0
DeviceH,Verizon,0,1,0,0
DeviceI,Verizon,0,1,0,0
DeviceJ,Verizon,0,1,0,0
DeviceK,Tmobile,1,1,0,1
DeviceL,Tmobile,1,0,1,0
DeviceM,Tmobile,0,1,0,0
DeviceN,Tmobile,0,1,0,0
DeviceO,Tmobile,0,1,0,0
```

plans Table

---

```
plan_id
vendor_id
name
```

Sample Data:

```
plan_id,vendor_id,name
PlanA,Sprint,Big Data Only Plan
PlanB,Verizon,Small Data Only Plan
PlanC,Sprint,300 Min Plan
PlanD,Verizon,900 Min Plan
PlanE,Verizon,Big Data Only Plan
PlanF,Tmobile,Small Data Only Plan
PlanG,Tmobile,300 Min Plan
PlanH,Tmobile,1000 Min Plan
```

plan_restrictions Table

---

```
restriction_id
vendor_id
plan_id
type
value
```

Sample Data:

```
restriction_id,vendor_id,plan_id,type,value
1,Sprint,PlanA,radio,3G
2,Sprint,PlanA,device_type,data
3,Verizon,PlanB,radio,4G
4,Sprint,PlanC,radio,3G
5,Sprint,PlanC,device_type,voice
6,Verizon,PlanD,radio,3G
7,Verizon,PlanD,device_type,voice
8,Verizon,PlanE,radio,3G
9,Verizon,PlanE,device_type,voice
10,Tmobile,PlanF,device_type,data
11,Tmobile,PlanG,device_type,voice
12,Tmobile,PlanH,device_type,voice
```

Restrictions keyed (I have closer to 50 actually, here is a same type of representation):

---

```
type / value possibilities
radio / 3g, 4g
device_type / data, voice
```

I am open to the possibility of restructuring the tables to make it easier to re-query, however I need to retain a certain amount of flexibility since I do have about 1000 models, 1000 plans, and about 2000 restrictions.

I personally think there is some sort of structure issue here, ie. models perhaps should have their elements as key/value pairs in a separate table, but that is even more complexity, and I haven't determined yet how to properly apply data driven restrictions in the first place.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing what you are talking about.  Would it be possible to get some sample data and desired output?

Comment: just a quick note, I have thought about putting a many to many table between plans and models and handling it that way, the only reason I am trying this path is because for the most part it is fair to say: Almost all the devices supported by each vendor can have almost every plan that vendor offers with minimal restrictions. I will upload some mock data for you Abe.

Comment: Dave, reading your comment about the hard coding of the restrictions, I would like to understand this problem better. Once vendor is selected we are left with some plans and models that we need to filter by restrictions. The main issue of your model is that the way you store type of Data/Voice/Raido on Model table is different from how it is stored in Restrictions. This means that before you can do simple INNER JOIN, you will need to do a simple transformation of Restrictions table. That will require some hard coding anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kicked this around for about the last hour with the other dba's here and think I solved it. I am posting this for anyone who finds themselves in a similar situation. The biggest problem was that I was too close to the data, and was trying enforce "meaningful" properties and restrictions between the plans needs and the models properties.. which isn't really necessary.

I can restructure my data to be in the following tables:

- Plans
- Restrictions
- Models

---

- Plans would have a many to many relationship to Restrictions
- Models would have a many to many relationship to Restrictions

---

I would solve the many to many relationships with intirum tables

- Plans_Restrictions
- Models_Restrictions

---

This would allow me to have stupid "Restrictions" such as a "Red Thing"

I would query as a chain:

- Plans
- Plans_Restrictions
- Restrictions
- Models_Restrictions
- Models

ie. To get all models with their properties information (restriction info) that are eligible for a plan I could use:

```
SELECT 
    M.* 
    ,R.*
FROM (
    SELECT P1.*
    FROM Plans P1
    WHERE id_vendor = @id_vendor
) P

INNER JOIN Plans_Restrictions PR
ON P.plan_id = PR.plan_id

INNER JOIN Restrictions R
ON PR.property = R.property

INNER JOIN Model_Restrictions MR
ON R.property = MR.property

INNER JOIN Model M
ON MR.model_id = M.model_id
```

And to get all the plans that are eligible for a model, i would reverse the 5 table chained join.

Thanks Abe.. writing this all down in detail to explain it, and understanding why your suggestion didn't solve my problem really helped me understand what my problem was and what I really needed to do. I don't think I would have solved it so fast without you.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should get you started:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM Plans as p
INNER JOIN plan_restriction as pr
ON p.plan_id = pr.plan_id
INNER JOIN models as m
ON pr.model_id = pr.model_id
WHERE p.vendor_id = 1 AND m.is_data = 1 AND is_4g = 1 AND ...
```

Comment: The crux of my dilemma is that I do not want to hard-code the restrictions into my SQL query.